# gevent monkey patching with flask run fails in debug mode

Tags: python, flask, python-3.6, gevent

I was trying to use `grequests` to make concurrent HTTP calls. To be able to test it on local, where I run flask dev server, I was trying to monkey patch gevent, where I'm facing some issues.

Here's my directory structure:

```
project_root/
    myapp/
        __init__.py
        app.py
        wsgi.py
        somepackage/
            module_using_grequest.py
```

`app.py` module contains functions to create flask app.

```
def create_app():
    ...
```

`wsgi.py` module initializes and stores `app` variable:

```
app = create_app()
```

So, I run the flask server like this:

```
FLASK_APP=myapp/wsgi.py flask run
```

When I run on production, I just run it via `gunicorn`, and set `worker_class=gevent`, which takes care of `monkey.patch_all()` internally. But for development server, I was trying to figure out the place to do patch_all. I thought that putting it in `myapp/__init__.py` would be better, since there is another import in `myapp/__init__.py` file. So, can't put it in `myapp/wsgi.py` file, because then `__init__.py` import will run before `patch_all()`.

So `myapp/__init__.py` becomes like this:

```
from gevent import monkey

monkey.patch_all()

# other imports
```

I would expect this to patch correctly. But when I run flask server in non-debug mode, I get this warning:

```
grequests.py:22: MonkeyPatchWarning: Patching more than once will result in the union of all True parameters being patched
```

But the server runs fine, and I'm able to use grequests methods.

But if I run this in debug mode, I get following warning:

```
FLASK_ENV=development FLASK_app=myapp/wsgi.py flask run

__init__.py:5: MonkeyPatchWarning: Monkey-patching outside the main native thread. Some APIs will not be available. Expect a KeyError to be printed at shutdown.
  monkey.patch_all()
__init__.py:5: MonkeyPatchWarning: Monkey-patching not on the main thread; threading.main_thread().join() will hang from a greenlet
  monkey.patch_all()
```

And it hangs there. The server doesn't run. Is there something I'm doing wrong? This one is on `gevent==21.1.2` version.

Earlier when I ran the same thing on `gevent==1.2.1`, it printed out following error:

```
/Users/rohitjain/sourcecode/project_root/__init__.py:5: RuntimeWarning: Monkey-patching not on the main thread; threading.main_thread().join() will hang from a greenlet
  monkey.patch_all()
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/rohitjain/.venvs/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 963, in inner
    fd=fd,
  File "/Users/rohitjain/.venvs/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 806, in make_server
    host, port, app, request_handler, passthrough_errors, ssl_context, fd=fd
  File "/Users/rohitjain/.venvs/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 694, in __init__
    server_address = get_sockaddr(host, int(port), self.address_family)
  File "/Users/rohitjain/.venvs/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 660, in get_sockaddr
    host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM, socket.IPPROTO_TCP
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 745, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
  File "/Users/rohitjain/.venvs/venv/bin/../lib/python3.6/encodings/__init__.py", line 100, in search_function
    level=0)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 152, in __exit__
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 107, in release
RuntimeError: cannot release un-acquired lock
```

And server hanged there.

Comment: How are you launching this on your dev server if you aren't also using gunicorn?

Comment: `flask run` It's there in the question.